# Delegate method not being called due to _delegate being nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

`ViewController`, uses another view controller, `MainViewController`, as a delegate. The line `[_delegate movePanelRight];` is supposed to be ran when a navigation item in `ViewController` is pressed. But when I put an `NSLog` in `movePanelRight`, which is found in `MainViewController.m`, this shows that `movePanelRight` is never run.

My navigation bar, for the initial view controller, is created in `AppDelegate.m`. This is also where the delegation code is done for `MainViewController.m`

I have used the following code to deduce that the delegate is `nil`. This is likely the cause of the method not being called.

```
if (_delegate == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Ah, you fool, delegate is nil!");
}
```

Hopefully this helps you solve the cause of the method `[_delegate movePanelRight];` not being called.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MainViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *viewController;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "SlideMenuController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    NSShadow* shadow = [NSShadow new];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                            NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aliquam" size:20.0f],
                                                            NSShadowAttributeName: shadow
                                                            }];

    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewControllerSB"];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    NSLog(@"Yeah, it's done!");
    return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)movePanelLeft;
- (void)movePanelRight;

@required
- (void)movePanelToOriginalPosition;

@end

#import "SlideMenuController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SlideMenuControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navigationItemMain;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *menuButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**ViewController.m - Class where the delegate method is called:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BasicSearchController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

ViewController *viewController;

// Interface variables
UIImageView *backgroundView;
UIImageView *backgroundDM;
UIImageView *underBarGradient;
UIBarButtonItem *searchButton;

// Screen dimensions variables
double screenWidth;
double screenHeight;
UIScreen *screen;
CGRect screenRect;

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize navigationItemMain;
@synthesize menuButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    menuButton.tag = 1;
    [self createInterface];
}

- (void) createInterface {
    screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background1.png"]];
    [backgroundView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    [backgroundView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [[self view] addSubview:backgroundView];
    [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:backgroundView];

    backgroundDM = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dm-for-background-final.png"]];
    [backgroundDM setFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth/4, (screenHeight/2)-(screenWidth/4), screenWidth/2, screenWidth/2)];
    [backgroundDM setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [[self view] addSubview:backgroundDM];
    [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:backgroundDM];

    underBarGradient = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient-under-bar.png"]];
    [underBarGradient setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, screenWidth, 3)];
    [underBarGradient setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [underBarGradient setAlpha:0.5f];
    [[self view] addSubview:underBarGradient];
    [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:underBarGradient];

    menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] landscapeImagePhone:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(presentMenu)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;

    searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-icon.png"] landscapeImagePhone:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(presentSearch)];

    navigationItemMain.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton;
    self.navigationItemMain.title = @"Welcome to DuoMatch";

    NSLog(@"UI created!");
}

- (IBAction) presentMenu {
    menuButton.tag = 1;
    switch (menuButton.tag) {
        case 0: {
            [_delegate movePanelToOriginalPosition];
            NSLog(@"Case 1!");
            break;
        }

        case 1: {
            [_delegate movePanelRight];
            NSLog(@"Case 2!");
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
        }
        NSLog(@"Menu presented!");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button tag is %ld", (long)menuButton.tag]);
}

- (void) presentSearch {
    NSLog(@"Search presented!");

    [self performSelector:@selector(pushBasicSearchController) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

`[_delegate movePanelRight];` is the line of code I am trying to call. The method movePanelRight is found in `MainViewController.m`. `NSLog`s, and the app itself, show the code is not being run, though `[self setupView]` (in the viewDidLoad of MainViewController.m) is being run, so the delegation appears to have worked.

**MainViewController.m** - Class containing the `movePanelRight` method:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SlideMenuController.h"

#define CENTER_TAG 1
#define LEFT_PANEL_TAG 2
#define CORNER_RADIUS 4

#define SLIDE_TIMING .25
#define PANEL_WIDTH 60

@interface MainViewController () <ViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SlideMenuController *slideMenuController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL showingMenuPanel;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Did Load/Unload

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupView];
}

- (void)setupView
{
    // setup center view
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navControllerSB"];
    self.viewController.view.tag = CENTER_TAG;
    self.viewController.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.viewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:_viewController];

    NSLog(@"View is set up!");

    [_viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (UIView *)getLeftView
{
    NSLog(@"I got left view!");
    // init view if it doesn't already exist
    if (_slideMenuController == nil)
    {
        // this is where you define the view for the left panel
        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                      bundle:nil];
        self.slideMenuController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlideMenuControllerSB"];
        self.slideMenuController.view.tag = LEFT_PANEL_TAG;
        self.slideMenuController.delegate = _viewController;

        [self.view addSubview:self.slideMenuController.view];

        [self addChildViewController:_slideMenuController];
        [_slideMenuController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        _slideMenuController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-20);
    }

    self.showingMenuPanel = YES;

    // set up view shadows
    [self showCenterViewWithShadow:YES withOffset:-2];

    UIView *view = self.slideMenuController.view;
    return view;
}

- (void)movePanelRight // to show left panel
{
    NSLog(@"XXXX Panel moved!");
    UIView *childView = [self getLeftView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:childView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIMING delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         _viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - PANEL_WIDTH, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {

                             _viewController.menuButton.tag = 0;
                         }
                     }];
    NSLog(@"Panel moved!");
}
```

To summarise once more: Why is the delegate method `movePanelRight` not called when it is run in `ViewController.m`? All help appreciated.

Comment: in your `-(void)setupView` method, could you set a breakpoint and step through, and make sure that `self.viewController` is properly instantiated-- and that it isn't nil by the time you try to set the `delegate` property on it?

Comment: Not directly related but your `delegate` property should be setup as `weak`, not `assign`. Using `assign` with object pointers is dangerous.

Comment: Some other issues: 1) In `ViewController.m`, you declare several variables from `viewController` down to `screenRect`. All of these are outside any class implementation. This makes all of these variables global. They are not instance variables if that is your intent. 2) You needlessly use `@synthesize` for two properties. No need. 3) In `ViewController viewDidLoad`, what is the point of creating another instance of `ViewController`? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @rmaddy if you have time, could you explain when should you use `assign`?  And why is it dangerous for object pointers?